# Charge NiMH using TP4056

Tags: batteries, charger, nimh

Is it possible to charge 3x NiMH AA (eneloops) in series with a TP4056 module?

I know that TP4056 will automatically cut off charging when Li-ion reaches 4.2v.

So 3x 1.2v Ni-MH = 3.6v, TP4056 starts charging.
When NiMH reaches 1.4v then it will be 4.2v in series and TP4056 shall stop?

btw my TP4056 module is modified to charge at 200mA rate instead of the default 1A rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Li-ion charging uses CC/CV charging. NiMH uses [ΔV/ΔT/Δt charging](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_metal_hydride). Attempting to use a Li-ion-only charger for a NiMH battery will damage it.

Comment: Well, if you overcharge it. If you don't aim for 100 % SOC and terminate too soon due to CV and timeout, you should be fine.